# Is this an efficient use of the Array.filter() method for searching and retrieving an Object instance from an Array?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, arrays, search

I am curious if this is an okay implementation of the `Array.filter()` method.

```
//Array of generic Object instances representing galleries. 
//The images property is empty for the example
var galleries:Array = new Array();

galleries[0] = {name: 'Portraits', images: new Array()};
galleries[1] = {name: 'Landscapes', images: new Array()};
galleries[2] = {name: 'Still Lifes', images: new Array()};

//Returns a gallery Object by the specified name
function getGallery(galleryName:String):Object
{
    function isGallery(element:*, index:int, arr:Array):Object 
    { 
        return (element.name == galleryName); 
    }

    var arr:Array = galleries.filter(isGallery);
    return arr[0];
}

var gallery:Object = getGallery('Landscapes');
if(gallery != null)
{
    trace(gallery.name);
}
else
{
    trace('Not found.');
}
```

This was the function I was using previously:

```
function getGallery(galleryName:String):Object
{
  for each(var gallery:Object in galleries)
  {
    if(galleryName == gallery.name)
    {
      return gallery;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

I was not able to figure out an implementation of the callback function for the `filter()` method, where the callback was outside of the `getGallery()` function. I wonder if there is a way to get the `isGallery` function outside of the `getGallery` scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am curious if this is an okay
>   implementation of the Array.filter()
>   method.

Not only your code is correct, it is a perfect example. for `Array.filter` usage.

> I was not able to figure out an
>   implementation of the callback
>   function for the filter() method,
>   where the callback was outside of the
>   getGallery() function.

It can be, but that beats the point - the idea of those callback functions is to be used mostly as anonymous functions, such as:

```
//Returns a gallery Object by the specified name
function getGallery(galleryName:String):Object
{
    return galleries.filter(function(gallery:*, idx:int, a:Array):Boolean { 
        return (gallery.name == galleryName); 
    }).shift();
}
```

Notice the compact code.

> I wonder if there is a way to get the
>   isGallery function outside of the
>   getGallery scope?

It's not possible directly, but it is possible if you make it a static function in the parent class, but why do so? See the above code example, it's so compact and reusable by itself.

---

As a side note, I would replace the whole `galleries` with:

```
var galleries:Object = {
    'Portraits': [],
    'Landscapes': [],
    'Still Lifes': []
};
```

So your 'getGallery' method becomes a O(1) operation:

```
galleries[name]
```

Comment: This was immensely helpful. The compact aspect of the anonymous function makes sense now. Also, your recommendation to make galleries an Object was brilliant. Thanks!